# Debian 3.1 (Sarge) init.d boot order

Tags: debian, boot

I am using a [TS-7800 single board computer](http://www.embeddedarm.com/products/board-detail.php?product=ts-7800) from Technologic Systems that ships with Debian 3.1 (Sarge).  I have updated it to Squeeze, but due to various driver issues I have been forced to roll back to Sarge.  I am attempting to configure the various drivers and configurations needed for my application services before they start. Ideally I would call one init.d script that contains the drivers / configurations then call the other init.d scripts (one for each process).

I am left scratching my head on how to guarantee the boot sequence.  I know in later versions of Debian I could use the [lbs-header](http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts/DependencyBasedBoot) to achieve this; but **is there anything comparable to the LBS header in Sarge?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually creating the symlinks, I'd recommend using the `update-rc.d` command to handle creating the symlinks for you in the appropriate runlevels.

For instance:

1. Create `/etc/init.d/myscript`
2. Run `update-rc.d /etc/init.d/myscript defaults 20`

The argument `defaults` states to use the default runlevels for starting and stoping the service and the argument `20` dictates the sequence number.

You can find more information at:

1. Question 11.6 of the [Debian GNU/Linux FAQ](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-customizing.en.html)
2. The Debian Administration article ["Making scripts run at boot time with Debian"](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/28)

Don't forget to daemonize your scripts if needed.

Comment: Aah great, I didn't have a sarge instance handy to check what the method was.  Understanding the mechanism is useful to the OP I reckon as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this yourself.  At boot up time scripts in `/etc/rcS.d` are executed first.  There are no actual scripts in here, just symlinks to `/etc/init.d/` scripts

They are prefixed with `Sxx` where xx is a number, and defines the sequence they are executed.

So lets say your script is `/etc/init.d/mydriverscript`, then

ln -s /etc/init.d/mydriverscript /etc/rcS.d/S01mydriverscript

And then it will execute at boot time before any other scripts.  If you'd prefer to run it only in specific run levels, then you can use the `/etc/rc3.d` folder instead, which will run it only if you are in runlevel 3.

Comment: This works great as far as the boot order. Now I just need to get the scripts to run correctly.  Thanks!